Linear mixed model. Model creation and how to plot results from mixed models?
I am new using linear mixed model. This is my problem. I have a dataset containing multiple echocardiography measuerement per patient over time. Some individuals have two echoes and some of them have up to 10, each echoe was performed a different time. I would like to see whether the change on each echoe parameters over time vary depending on the kindey function. I have the following variables:

StudyID
Average_Ee (continous)
eGFR (categorical/ 3 categories)
year.0 (centered time in years)
age_c (centered age)
sex    (dichotomous)
Hypertension (dichotomous)
Diabetes (dichotomous)
CVD    (dichotomous)
HF_icd (dichotomous)

Example model and results

Is this model correct for my aim? or is there a better approach?
Also, how can I plot the results from the mixed models?
Thanks in advance, any guide is highly appreciated. :)

Hi Cindy. Your first question is a statistics question, which we usually don't answer on this site about programming. You could try stats.stackexchange.com, but be aware that your question is very broad, and has little detail about what you actually want to do, so it will be hard to answer. The second question about plotting is a programming question, but again very broad. What do you want to plot exactly? What have you tried so far?
